# Strong typedefs

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

Is there any way to make a complete copy of a type so that they can be distinguished in template deduction context? Take the example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct test
{
    static int c()
    { 
        static int t = 0;
        return t++;
    }
};

typedef int handle;

int main()
{
    std::cout << test<int>::c() << std::endl;
    std::cout << test<handle>::c() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since typedef only makes an alias for a type, this prints 0, 1 
instead of the desired 0, 0. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Take a look at [Boost strong typedef](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/),

> Note that **neither typedef nor using create new distinct data types.
>   They only create synonyms of existing types.** That means that the type
>   of myword above, declared with type WORD, can as well be considered of
>   type unsigned int; it does not really matter, since both are actually
>   referring to the same type.

Since `int` and `handle` are *one and the same*, the output `0 1` is expected.

There's a workaround though, as @interjay suggests.

You can use [`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html).

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF( int , handle );
```

Comment: The question is to find an alternative to `typedef` that won't have this behavior.

Comment: I don't think there is an alternative to `typedef`, that is the point I'm trying to highlight.

Comment: There isn't one built into the language, but that doesn't mean one can't be built (e.g. the link I posted above).

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you are not planning to post an answer, may I edit my answer to add your link?

Comment: Thanks to you @interjay, I learnt a new thing today. :)

Comment: Yes I was aware that typedef doesn't provide the desired behavior. The link looks very promising!

Comment: BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF has two problems. It doesn't work for user-defined types and multiple typedefs of the same primitive are not distinguished in template deductions. I wrote an answer addressing these problems.

Comment: That's great work. But, you didn't have to unaccept my answer for that.

Comment: @shauryachats actually I think I missclicked somewhere. Back to accepted!

Comment: @Veritas only supporting privitive types is no problem imho, but I found no evidence for your second claim. Afaik the purpose of BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF is introduce a type that is also for templates considered as a distinct type. Do you have a reference/example ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I made an example program to play with BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF which confirms the second claim: https://gist.github.com/MaxBarraclough/088047135c1a1d7767f5ec82199c7815

Comment: @MaxBarraclough the "second claim" is that they are not distinguished in template deductions. Thats not what your example is about. See here for a working example about template parameter deduction: https://godbolt.org/z/fWEjMj. Actually it is similar to what OP is asking for here. And it does work! In your example there are implicit conversions, thats a different issue. I have to do some research to say anything about that

Comment: @MaxBarraclough BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF is just not meant to surpress implicit conversions, its part of their example https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html. See `y = x;      // other operations permitted as a is converted as necessary` what you call "RENDERING THE WHOLE THING POINTLESS." is by design. You misunderstood what BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEFs are made for

Comment: @MaxBarraclough Suppose `char` is unsigned then you also do not get an error for assigning a `char` to a `unsigned char`, yet they are two distinct types

Comment: here again the link to a working demo: https://godbolt.org/z/fWEjMj. Maybe you want to modify it and add it to the answer

Comment: @idclev463035818 *In your example there are implicit conversions, thats a different issue.* Thanks I'd missed that, makes sense. I might add a static assert showing that they're different types.

Comment: @MaxBarraclough `typedef int x;` is only introducing a different name for `int`, you cannot have a distinct type without some boilerplate and only thats what the strong typedef gives you. Having a different type does not imply that you cannot convert between them

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thanks, but I'm familiar with how typedef works. I've already acknowledged the point about implicit conversions.

Answer (score 5):

Either as suggested BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF

```
template<typename>
struct test {
    static int c() {
        static int t = 0;
        return t++ ;
    } 
};

//Instead of 
//typedef int handle

BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(int , handle) ;  

int main() {

    std::cout << test<int>::c() << std::endl
    std::cout << test<handle>::c() << std::endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

Output : 0 0  , because handle is **not** int but a type implicitly convertable to int .

if you don't want to use BOOST_STRONG_TYPE then simply  add second parameter 
to your class template :

```
template<typename, unsigned int N>
struct test {
    static int c() {
        static int t = 0;
        return t++ ;
    }

};
```

Thus making `test<int, 0>` and `test<handle, 1>` different types

```
int main() {

    std::cout << test<int, 0>::c() << std::endl ;
    std::cout << test<handle,1>::c() << std::endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

Output : 0 0

You can also add macro to generate your types :

```
#define DEFINE_TEST_TYPE(type) \
typedef test<type, __COUNTER__> test_##type;


template<typename, unsigned int N>
struct test {    
     static int c() {
        static int t = 0;
        return t++ ;   
    }
};

typedef int handle ;

DEFINE_TEST_TYPE(int) ;
DEFINE_TEST_TYPE(handle) ;

int main() {
    std::cout << test_int::c() << std::endl ;
    std::cout << test_handle::c() << std::endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regarding your now-deleted question abour your open-source project, you could ask that on relevant Reddit communities. If you do ask it in more than one sub though, do ensure you declare your cross-posting, so people can avoid making duplicate answers.